# excluding files in Pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

In the spec file created by Pyinstaller when compiling i have added

```
excludes=["mfc90u.dll", "mfc90.dll"],
```

but after compiling these two files can be found in the compiled directory.  BUT when I add the line

```
excludes=["FixTk", "tcl", "tk", "tkinter", "Tkinter"],
```

it works perfectly. The mfc90u.dll and mfc90.dll causes an error when converting the files to the Windows AppX format and I would like to exclude them.
How can i prevent the files and folders i want from being added TO THE compilation?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me ('a' is the Analysis object):

```
a.binaries = TOC([x for x in a.binaries if x[0] not in excludes])
```

Answer (score 0):

**any files and folders that are not necessary can be removed.**

first with directory mode, manually you can explore deleting doubtful huge files and testing for its working.

then update spec to exclude not necessary `datas` or `binaries`

more details on:
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/discussions/6126